# WSS 3.0: change parent type for a content type

Tags: sharepoint, wss

I have created a hierarchy of content types. The root of my hierarchy has the content type "Document" as a parent. There are about 20 other content types derived from my root.

Now, I want to change the parent from "Document" to something else. Is it possible? Either in the web interface or in code? Can the definition of content types be dumped to a text file and then recreated? Or any other trick?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can create a feature that contains all your custom content types, you will be able to change the XML that defines each content type and it's columns.

This will give you the ability to change the content types for your site by removing the feature and installing it again with the changes (using a Solution is best).

Note that any content using the older content types will still use them after updating the feature (content types are stored at the site level, list level and on the actual item).